# override sessionDidReceiveChallenge method to bypass server trust issue in Alamofire5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, alamofire5

Hi all we were using alamofire 4.9.1 before and recently i have upgraded to Alamofire 5 and with that we are facing bellow error

**The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “XXX.XXX.XX.X” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,**

**In Alamofire 4.9.1, we had resolve same issue by override didReceive challenge method as bellow**

```
delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
               var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling
               var credential: URLCredential?

               if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
                   disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
                   credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
               } else {
                   if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                       disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
                   } else {
                       credential = WebAPIManager.manager.session.configuration.urlCredentialStorage?.defaultCredential(for: challenge.protectionSpace)
                       if credential != nil {
                           disposition = .useCredential
                       }
                   }
               }
               return (disposition, credential)
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

*I have the same situation, and I am trying to refactor and adapt to the new version. So far I am finding this code in swift 5: And I still haven't determined where I can get "URLSessionTask" and "URLAuthenticationChallenge" from.*

Code :

let delegate = SessionDelegate()

```
            let delegateQueue:OperationQueue = .init()
    
            delegateQueue.underlyingQueue = .global(qos: .background)
    
            let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.af.default, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: delegateQueue)
    
            let manager = Alamofire.Session(session: session, delegate: SessionDelegate(), rootQueue: .global(qos: .background))
    
    
    
    manager.delegate.urlSession(session, task: <#T##URLSessionTask#>, didReceive: <#T##URLAuthenticationChallenge#>) { (<#URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition#>, <#URLCredential?#>) in
        <#code#>
    }
```